# Smoothen grouped ggplot line charts with different lengths

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying the slightly smoothen the lines in my grouped line chart which looks like this:
I am trying using this:

```
temp %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(use_cohort), y = avg_txn, group = as.numeric(activation_cohort), color = as.factor(activation_cohort))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  stat_smooth(aes(x=use_cohort,y=avg_txn))+
  geom_label(aes(label =label), nudge_x = 0.35, size = 4, na.rm = TRUE) + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, 200))
```

[image: the result]

Comment: Please run `dput(temp)` and add the result to your question. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks